# Chapter title in a colored box (custom chapter command)

Tags: formatting, titles

I try to put my document's title in a colored box. I looked for it on google and on this forum but I didn't find anything I like (\titleformat, …). I've already renew the chapter command (in my .sty file) and I would like to find a way to put the colored box in this renewed command… Unfortunately, I have a lot to learn yet and to understand in Latex :-(

```
% Chapter Title redefinition
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}%
                    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                    {\noindent\fontsize{18}{20}\fontspec{Arial}\selectfont\color{my_custom_color}}}
```

[EDIT]
For now, I've that :
[image]

And I would like to have that
[image]

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Package definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\ProvidesPackage{ffgTemplate}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Required Package
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\RequirePackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  % Gestion des marges
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}                                  % Gestion du français
\RequirePackage{graphicx}                                       % Gestion des images
\RequirePackage{xcolor}                                         % Gestion des couleurs
\RequirePackage{hyperref}                                       % Gestion des hyperliens
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}                                       % Gestion des en-têtes et pieds de pages.
\RequirePackage{pifont}                                         % Gestion des symbols (\ding{55} dans le footer)
\RequirePackage{array}                                          % Gestion (améliorée) des tableaux
\RequirePackage{ulem}                                           % Gestion (avancée) des soulignements
\RequirePackage{textcomp}                                       % Caractères additionnels
\RequirePackage{mathtools, amsmath, amstext, amssymb, amsthm}   % Package de l'AMS + mathtools
\RequirePackage{gensymb}                                        % symbole \degree
\RequirePackage{cancel}
\RequirePackage{nicefrac}                                       % Gestion des fractions
\RequirePackage{xspace}                                         % Gestion intelligente de l'espace après une commande
\RequirePackage{lmodern}                                        % Police de caractère
\RequirePackage{calc}                                           % Syntaxe naturelle pour les calculs
\RequirePackage{framed}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}                                      % Pour créer des boites colorées.

% Layout fisrt page
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}                                % Gestion du background de la page de garde.
\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}                      % Gestion des positions du texte (option de config : showboxes)
\RequirePackage{fontspec}                               % Gestion de "arial" ET "arial narrow" comme font.
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}                            % Gestion des tailles de police hors dictionnaire
\RequirePackage{shadowtext}                             % Gestion des ombres
% \RequirePackage{UniversalSans}

% Layout Document 
\RequirePackage{titlesec}                               % Gestion des sections
\RequirePackage{titletoc}                               % Gestion de la table des matière
\RequirePackage{titling}                                % Gestion des titres
\RequirePackage{enumitem}                               % Gestion des listes

% Tools kit
\RequirePackage{fancybox}                               % pour dessiner des boites ;-)
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}                               % Renew command & robust command
\RequirePackage{float}

% other package
\RequirePackage{bm}                                     % Notation mathématique en gras
\RequirePackage{lscape}                                 % Gestion du mode "paysage"

\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Define global variable for document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\def\federationName{F.f.G.}
\def\federationAcronym{FfG}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% (Re)Define parametres for document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\setmainfont{Arial}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}                  % Définition du mot pour les tableaux
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}                  % Définition du mot pour les Figures

% Color definition
\definecolor{ffg_darkblue}{RGB}{21,29,76}
\definecolor{ffg_lightblue}{RGB}{0, 120, 190}
\definecolor{ffg_red}{RGB}{241, 83, 60}
\definecolor{ffg_title_color}{RGB}{12, 97, 158}
\definecolor{footer_color}{RGB}{128, 128, 128}
\definecolor{flyingblue}{RGB}{49, 123, 181}
\definecolor{greymoreknowledge}{RGB}{200, 200, 200}

% Parametres for TextPos
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{5mm}{5mm}                                      % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                     % Pas d'indentation au placement du texte

\setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\fbox{$~~~ \displaystyle#1 ~~~$}}

\newcommand\NextYear{%
   \advance\year by 1 \the\year\advance\year by -1}
    

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Image's first page definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{firstpage.png}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
}

\shadowoffset{3pt}
\shadowrgb{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% First Page's definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\def\maketitle{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%

    % Titre du document
    \begin{textblock}{200}(0,3)
        \centering
        {\fontsize{33}{42}\selectfont {\bfseries \textcolor{ffg_darkblue}{FORMATION~\formationType~\discipline}\par}}
        {\fontsize{33}{42}\selectfont {\bfseries \textcolor{ffg_red}{Module :\\\moduleTitle}\par}}
    \end{textblock}

    % Type de document
    \begin{textblock}{200}(0,8)
        \begin{center}
            {\fontsize{28}{42}\selectfont \textcolor{ffg_lightblue}{Formation des Cadres}\par}%
        \end{center}
    \end{textblock}

    % Années
    \begin{textblock}{200}(0,11.5)
        \centering
        \begin{center}
            {\fontsize{30}{84}\selectfont \textcolor{white}{{\the\year}\hspace{3cm} {\NextYear}}\par}%
        \end{center}
    \end{textblock}

    \null
    \cleardoublepage
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Other page definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% \setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
\fancypagestyle{followingpage}{%
    \fancyhf{}

    %% Footer
    \fancyfootoffset{3cm}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\hspace{2.5cm} {\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont \textit{\textcolor{footer_color}{Formation des Cadres~\discipline \hfill p.\thepage \hfill Edition \the\year~-~\NextYear}}} \hspace{2.5cm}}
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Titles layout redefinition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\makeatletter

% Chapter Title redefinition
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}%
                    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                    {\noindent\fontsize{18}{20}\fontspec{Arial}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}}

% \titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}
% \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
% {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}

% Section Title redefinition
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                        {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                        {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                        {\noindent\fontsize{14}{12}\fontspec{Arial}\selectfont\color{ffg_lightblue}}}


% SubSection Title redefinition
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                        {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                        {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                        {\noindent\fontsize{13}{20}\fontspec{Arial}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{followingpage}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Redefine Theoreme & Definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\newtheoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
{\topsep}       % space before
{\topsep}       % space after
{
    \itshape
}               % body font
{}              % indent
{\bfseries}     % header font
{}              % punctuation
{\newline}      % after theorem header
{
    \thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{\ -\ #3}\\*[-1.5ex]
}% header specification (empty for default)

\theoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
\newtheorem*{definitionT}{\color{ffg_title_color}{Définition}}
\newenvironment{definition}
{
    \begin{leftbar}
        \begin{definitionT}
            \mbox{}\noindent\ignorespaces}{
        \end{definitionT}
    \end{leftbar}
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Define colorbox
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\newtcolorbox{knowledgebox}{colback=ffg_red!5!white, colframe=ffg_red!100!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, title={Savoir}, breakable} %breakable
\newtcolorbox{skillsbox}{colback=flyingblue!5!white, colframe=flyingblue!100!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, title={Savoir faire}, breakable} %breakable
\newtcolorbox{morebox}{colback=greymoreknowledge!5!white, colframe=greymoreknowledge!100!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, title={Allez plus loin\ldots}, breakable}
\newtcolorbox{dangerbox}[1]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!100!black, fonttitle=\bfseries, title={Important}, breakable} %breakable
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: A priori, it should be easy to do with `titlesec`, but  you don't   give any details on  what you'd like to obtain.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've now add some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go, with `titlesec` and `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\newcommand{\bgparbox}[1]{\colorbox{blue}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\fboxsep}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}#1\end{tabularx}}}
\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge}
 {}
 {0em}
 {\bgparbox{\thechapter & #1}}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction. \break A detailed introduction}

\lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I've some questions : 1) Why a tabular ? 2) is it possible to have the same result with all the code line in my sty file ?

Comment: Please ask them!

Comment: I hope to find a solution applicable in my .sty file so I can have a template file and files with content/informations. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you load `titlesec` so  it should work and might easily be adaptable to the colour to have. I'm not so sure with your`hard-coded redefinition of `\chapter`, which should probably be defined in terms of `\titleformat`.

Comment: So you said that it's better (more elegant, more efficient, … ) if I use `titlesec` in place of `\renewcommand{\chapter}`. I'm right ? Can I put everything I've write in `renewcommand` in the `titlesec` ? Sorry, may be it's a dummy question but i'm a noob in LaTeX

Comment: @Gregg: I didn't mean it's more elegant or efficient – I simply don't see why one should reinvent the wheel when there already exist dedicated packages which work well. Formatting commands  can be put in `\titleformat` (I've tested loading Arial with fontspec,  it runs fine) and spacing commands in `\titlespacing` (if you don't use the latter command, the default spacing for the document class will be used).

Comment: When I put your piece of code `\newcommand{\bgparbox}[1]{\colorbox{blue}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\fboxsep}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}#1\end{tabularx}}}
\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\huge}
 {}
 {0em}
 {\bgparbox{\thechapter & #1}}%` I have an error : `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@chapter. 1`… It's seems like i misuse the #1 param or may be it's because it's in a .sty file... I'm lost...

Comment: @Gregg  Did you load titlesec with the `[explicit]` option?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Bernard. Here's my partial solution :

```
\definecolor{ffg_title_color}{RGB}{12, 97, 158}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{ffg_title_color}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\fontsize{16pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{white}\begin{shaded*}}
    {\thechapter \qquad #1}
    {0pt}
    {\end{shaded*}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
```

[image]
Why "partial" solution ? Because it's not perfect : there is to much "space" under the title. As you can see, the vertical space above the title (in the colored box) is not the same (smaller) than the space under the title (always in the colored box). I try yet to solve this problem (make the under part smaller) but all the other parts are perfect what I want.